# Cant get facebook date range working for events in ruby/koala

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using ruby koala facebook graph API gem to retrieve events but cant restrict the events using a date range.  I seem to be getting all events (even ones which have happened).  What I am trying to do is get events is the next 200 days. I am using the following (ruby) code:

```
 Koala.config.api_version = 'v2.10'
 oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new app_id, app_secret
 graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new oauth.get_app_access_token

 from_date = Date.today
 to_date   = from_date + 200

 fb_events = graph.get_object( fb_venue["url_listings"] + "?time_range={\"since\":#{from_date}, \"until\":#{to_date}" )
```

I am then getting the events 25 at once (the facebook default limit) using 'fb_events.next_page' to get them all.

I seem to get getting all events, including ones is the past.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `#get_object` method wants a query string like that? Based on the docs[1], it seems that you should pass your object ID (which I assume is in fb_venue['url_listings'] for you as a first arg, and then metadata in a subsequent arg as a Hash. So I'd try something like:

```
fb_events = graph.get_object(fb_venue['url_listings'], 
    {since: from_date, until: to_date})
```

...according to the key/nesting structure FB expects.

*Edit: forgot link to docs.*

*[1] -
 http://www.rubydoc.info/github/arsduo/koala/Koala%2FFacebook%2FGraphAPIMethods%3Aget_object*

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc I don't think that you can request all the events, You can only select an event by using `/{event-id}` like this [example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=399798340230560&version=v2.10) or you can get user's events but you will need to ask him for the permission according to 
[permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_events).

> add `user_events` to the list of scope that you are permitting from user.

By this when user sign up using Facebook to your application it will take a permission for his events.

After that by using `graph.get_object({facebook-user-id} + '/events')` you will get 25 of his events as a default value and you can add `{limit: 5}` as a second parameter to the `get_object` function, You can use `until` and `since` but they should be in `A Unix timestamp` look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging) to see the needed date format, hope this would help.